# Prove that if $\langle T(v),v\rangle=0$ for every $v\in V$ then $T=0$. Show that the same result is not true over $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, inner-products

***Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ and $T\in L(V)$. Prove that if $\langle T(v),v\rangle=0$ for every $v\in V$ then $T=0$. Give an example to show that the same result is not true if $V$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$.***

**My attempt:**

*I first thought doing the following:*

If $\langle T(v),v\rangle=0$ for every $v\in V$ that means $T(v)\in V^{\perp}=\{0\} $ , then $T(v)=0$ for every $v\in V$ and then $T=0$

*Second, I tried another proof:*

If $\langle T(v),v\rangle=0$ for every $v\in V$, then $\langle T(v),v\rangle=\langle v,T(v)\rangle$ what means $T$ is self adjoint $(T=T^*)$ and positive, then, if the dimension of the space is finite, there exist $F\in L(V)$ invertible such that $T=F^*F$ but in this case:

$\langle T(v),v\rangle=\langle F^*F(v),v\rangle=\langle F(v),F(v)\rangle=\lVert F(v)\rVert^2=0$ then $F(v)=0$ and $F=0$ what means $T=0$

How can I do a general proof that doesn't require finite dimensional vector space?

If $V$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, we can consider

$[T]_{can}=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$ and in this case, $\langle T(e_1),e_1\rangle=0$ and $\langle T(e_2),e_\rangle=0$ but $T\neq 0$

What am I doing wrong?

*Edit:*

As everything I did before doesn't work, I tried to think that if V is a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ then we can find a eigenvalue $\lambda$ with eigenvector $v$ so, we have $0=\langle T(v),v\rangle=\langle\lambda v,v\rangle=\lambda\langle v,v\rangle=\lambda ||v||$ and $\lambda=0$ because $v\neq 0$, we can conlude then that every eigenvalue has to be zero but I don't know how to continue here. What happens when a operador has only zero eigenvalues?

Comment: Use `\langle` and `\rangle`, not `<` and `>`. Compare $\langle T(e_1),e_1\rangle$ with $<T(e_1),e_1>$. MathJax thinks that `<` and `>` are operators, so it adds extra equal space on both sides. Whereas `\langle` and `\rangle` are delimeters so the spacing takes that into account (plus, they are taller).

Comment: For your very last question $\langle T(v),v \rangle$ isn't linear in $v$, so it's not enough to just prove an equality holds on a basis to have it be true for all vectors. (And in fact, look at the vector $(1,1)$ to see how things fail.)

Comment: P.S.: "Vector space", not "vectorial space". "Ajoint", not "Adjunct".

Comment: *"What happens when a operador has only zero eigenvalues?"* There is a workaround -- focus on hermitian and skew-hermitian (finite dim) operators.  I.e. $\langle T(v),v\rangle=\frac{1}{2}\langle (T+T^*)(v),v\rangle+\frac{1}{2}\langle (T-T^*)(v),v\rangle$, where the hermitian form is purely real and the skew (hermitian) form is purely imaginary, so divide and conquer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are doing several things wrong, unfortunately.

1. The condition $\langle T(v),v\rangle=0$ does not mean that $T(v)\in V^{\perp}$ for all $v$: you are not saying that $\langle T(v),x\rangle=0$ for all $x$, you are only saying that $T(v)$ is perpendicular to $v$. So your first thought is incorrect. You cannot conclude that $T(v)\in V^{\perp}$.
2. Same problem with your second attempt. For $T$ to be self-adjoint you need $\langle T(x),y\rangle = \langle x,T(y)\rangle$ **for all** $x$ and $y$, not just when $x=y$. So you cannot conclude from $\langle T(v),v\rangle = \langle v,T(v)\rangle$ for all $v$ that $T$ is self-adjoint.
3. Your example doesn't work: note that $T(1,1) = (1,1)$, so $\langle T(1,1),(1,1)\rangle = 2\neq 0$. Just because each basis vector maps to a vector that is orthogonal to it does not mean that *every* vector is mapped to a vector that is orthogonal to it. 
    We can check a property just on a basis when we have some kind of linearity. But here what we have is an assignment that sends the vector $v$ to the scalar $\langle T(v),v\rangle$. This is not linear: because $v+w$ is mapped to $$\langle T(v+w),v+w\rangle = \langle T(v),v\rangle + \langle T(v),w\rangle + \langle T(w),v\rangle + \langle T(w),w\rangle,$$ and not to $\langle T(v),v\rangle+\langle T(w),w\rangle$. So checking the condition on a basis does not allow you to conclude it holds at *every* vector. 
   But maybe if instead of a reflection (your example), you try a rotation?

Note that neither of your attempted proofs ever uses the fact that you are working over $\mathbb{C}$, so there must surely be something wrong in them.

Comment: Can I suggest you add the fact from my comment (on the question) to your answer? I think students get used to seeing things proved just on a basis, and don't realize that linearity is required for that thing to extend to the entire space. This is a nice instance of why one can't just assume linearity.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC Fair enough, but I'm too wordy to just phrase it that way....

Comment: Heh. Fair enough indeed. Use whatever and as many words as you like. :-) I just imagine some student crying out "Wait! You only showed things on a basis in the past. Why can't i do that here?" If I were teaching this I would take the opportunity to mention, or maybe even demonstrate, that that inner product was not linear in $v$, so they don't get lazy and assume everything is linear. But it's already a nice compete answer even without that point too.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC Well, the linear product is introduced as being sesquilinear, and has two arguments anyway. It's not the inner product, but rather the function $V\to\mathbf{F}$ given by $v\longmapsto \langle T(v),v\rangle$ that is not linear.

Comment: Yup. Nicely stated.

Answer (score 2):

we have  $$\langle Tx,y\rangle =\frac{1}{4} (\langle T(x+y),x+y\rangle-\langle T(x-y),x-y\rangle+\langle T(x+iy),x+iy\rangle-\langle T(x-iy),x-iy\rangle)$$,So if $\forall v\in V,\langle T(v),v\rangle=0$, then we conclude that $\forall x,y \in V;\langle Tx,y\rangle =0$, in particular for $y=Tx$, so $T=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider for example for $T$ in the plane a rotation of $\pi/2$ then
$\langle T(v),v\rangle=0$ for all $v$. $T$ is  not $0$.

Comment: Use `\langle` instead of `<` for the left delimiter; use `\rangle` instead of `>` for the right delimiter.